# Ubuntu 20.04lts hibernates fine, suspend kills pci wifi

Tags: hibernate, resume

Gateway E-475M 64-bit laptop dual boot with WIN7PRO 64-bit and UBUNTU 20.04.4LTS

Problem: I can suspend and the wifi won't detect anything after resuming... no icon on the top bar, and going to select network the whole thing is empty...  but, afterwards, I reboot fresh then I can go into hibernate and wifi is fine upon restore. (WIN7PRO boot does not have any wifi issues going on/off sleep mode, and even hibernates with no wifi issues). pci wifi comes up as Intel Pro wireless 3945ABG which uses the iwl3945 driver. (info: hardware scanning is faster and more reliable and so is recommended for use with Network-Manager. But unfortunately “iwl3945” driver does not support hardware scanning very well, however it is a default behavior that Network-Manager expects)

Tried all the network manager restart variations (modprobe, etc.) w/no result. Nothing wakes the pci wifi... nothing!

HERE is the results of lsmod | egrep 'module|iwp|iwl' and dmesg | grep -i iwl

(clearing dmesg first, fresh boot, wifi working in first report - then suspending, then resuming and wifi went out as seen in the next report):

```
> batgirl@batgirl-E-475M:~/Desktop$ lsmod | egrep 'module|iwp|iwl'
>iwl3945                94208  0
>iwlegacy              114688  1 iwl3945
>mac80211             1228800  2 iwl3945,iwlegacy
>cfg80211              954368  3 iwl3945,iwlegacy,mac80211
>batgirl@batgirl-E-475M:~/Desktop$ 
>
>batgirl@batgirl-E-475M:~/Desktop$ dmesg | grep -i iwl
>[   20.703742] iwl3945: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG/BG Network Connection driver for Linux, in-tree:s
>[   20.703748] iwl3945: Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation
>[   20.703750] iwl3945: hw_scan is disabled
>[   20.703825] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
>[   20.767591] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Tunable channels: 11 802.11bg, 13 802.11a channels
>[   20.767601] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel Wireless WiFi Link 3945ABG
>[   20.767967] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-3945-rs'
>[   25.556001] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
>[   61.110020] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 15.32.2.9
>
>goto suspend, then resume...
>
batgirl@batgirl-E-475M:~/Desktop$ dmesg | grep -i iwl
>[   20.703742] iwl3945: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG/BG Network Connection driver for Linux, in-tree:s
>[   20.703748] iwl3945: Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation
>[   20.703750] iwl3945: hw_scan is disabled
>[   20.703825] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
>[   20.767591] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Tunable channels: 11 802.11bg, 13 802.11a channels
>[   20.767601] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel Wireless WiFi Link 3945ABG
>[   20.767967] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-3945-rs'
>[   25.556001] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
>[   61.110020] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 15.32.2.9
>[  316.050830] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: can't change power state from D3hot to D0 (config space inaccessible)
>[  320.045831] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 696 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlegacy/common.c:97 _il_grab_nic_access+0xa8/0xc0 [iwlegacy]
>[  320.045831] Modules linked in: ccm binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event ttm iwl3945 drm_kms_helper pcmcia snd_rawmidi iwlegacy snd_seq mac80211 coretemp snd_seq_device cec cfg80211 rc_core yenta_socket pcmcia_rsrc i2c_algo_bit joydev fb_sys_fops wmi_bmof snd_timer syscopyarea input_leds sysfillrect serio_raw libarc4 at24 pcmcia_core snd sysimgblt tifm_7xx1 tifm_core soundcore mac_hid sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid sdhci_pci lpc_ich pata_acpi hid psmouse firewire_ohci firewire_core cqhci ahci i2c_i801 i2c_smbus crc_itu_t libahci sdhci e1000e wmi video
>[  320.045831] RIP: 0010:_il_grab_nic_access+0xa8/0xc0 [iwlegacy]
>[  320.045831]  il_wr_prph+0x35/0x90 [iwlegacy]
>[  320.045831]  il_apm_init+0x1be/0x230 [iwlegacy]
>[  320.045831]  il3945_apm_init+0x1f/0x150 [iwl3945]
>[  320.045831]  il3945_hw_nic_init+0x33/0x560 [iwl3945]
>[  320.045831]  __il3945_up.part.0+0x70/0x140 [iwl3945]
>[  320.045831]  il3945_mac_start+0x70/0x1c0 [iwl3945]
>[  320.990337] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  320.990353] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  321.117510] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  321.117519] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  321.244966] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  321.244973] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  321.372096] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  321.372102] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  321.499218] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  321.499223] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  321.500047] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to initialize device after 5 attempts.
>[  322.513903] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  322.513917] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  322.641250] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  322.641261] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  322.768839] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  322.768848] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  322.896142] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  322.896151] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  323.023431] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  323.023441] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  323.023800] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to initialize device after 5 attempts.
>[  323.958924] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  323.958940] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  324.086102] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  324.086112] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  324.213359] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  324.213372] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  324.340481] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  324.340487] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  324.467607] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
>[  324.467613] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
>[  324.467995] iwl3945 0000:02:00.0: Unable to initialize device after 5 attempts.
```

Really crashes bad and isn't recoverable with any network-manager stuff – anyone got any idea what's causing this? Using a usb wifi and suspends/hibernates fine ~ same with network cable, suspends/hibernates alright...

P.S. - after booting up and suspending for the first time, it will often (not always) resume with pci wifi working fine... but after suspending for second or third time, it'll go dead and won't work again after resuming until reboot. Yet, I can hibernate for weeks on end and it restores with pci wifi intact every time... well, until I try to suspend then it's hit or miss on when it'll go dead again requiring reboot ;-\

ADDENDA: fyi - tried all the following and NOTHING will waken the pci wifi once resumed from suspend except rebooting ~

> ```
> sudo systemctl stop network-manager
> sudo systemctl start network-manager
> sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
>
> sudo modprobe -r iwl3945
> sudo modprobe iwl3945
> sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
>
> sudo service network-manager restart  <--- supposed to restart network to restore
>                                             crashed wifi status
> sudo systemctl status network-manager.service   <--- good too - maybe?
> ifconfig <------------------------------------------ info
>
>
> sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 power on  <-----------
>
>
> nmcli networking off
> nmcli networking on
>
> nmcli radio wifi off
> nmcli radio wifi on <---cuts dropdown wifi from off to on
> nmcli nm wifi on   ???
>
>
> Intel PRO/Wireless 3945ABG
>
>
> sudo iwlist scan
>
> lspci -knn | grep Ether -A2
> lspci -knn | grep Net -A2  <-------
>
> sudo hwinfo --network   <------- !
>
> lsmod | grep iwl3945
>
> sudo modprobe -r iwl3945
>
> sudo rmmod iwl3945 && sudo modprobe iwl3945
>
> sudo rfkill unblock wifi; sudo rfkill unblock all
>
> sudo modprobe iwl3945
>
>
> sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
>
> ifconfig wlan0
> sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
> sudo ifconfig wlan0 up  <-------------
>
> lsmod | egrep 'module|iwp|iwl'
>
>
>
>
> sudo rmmod -f iwl3945
> sudo modprobe iwl3945 disable_hw_scan=1  <---this may have fixed it? Nope...
>
> dmesg | grep -i iwl
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> For Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and 20.04 LTS with GNOME desktop purging network-manager package will also purge ubuntu-desktop and
> ```
>
> gnome-control-center (essential part of GNOME desktop). So it is not
> an option.
>
> ```
> Here you should disable NetworkManager service (as you have already done):
>
> sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
> sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
>
> and three more services:
>
> sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager-wait-online.service
> sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
>
> sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
> sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
>
> sudo systemctl stop network-manager.service
> sudo systemctl disable network-manager.service
>
> and then reboot.
> ```

Comment: I miss in the question what `rfkill list all` states  ( https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/rfkill.8.html ) after a suspend and no wifi. And if `rfkill unblock wlp2s0` works?

Comment: yeah, tried that too - list shows it not blocked.... so unblock no joy :-\

Comment: Using 'systemctl hibernate' as hot key to hibernate fine, so opened terminal and tried 'systemctl suspend', then 'pm-suspend', then 's2ram' - but all of them only lost pci wifi upon restore... any other way to suspend to try?

Answer (score 0):

Fix for

> BSM uCode verification failed

is to disable power saving.

In `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d` search for `wifi.powersave` If it is "3" alter it to "2". The file to edit is probably named `default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`.

Probably explains this behaviour:

> after booting up and suspending for the first time, it will often (not always) resume with pci wifi working fine... but after suspending for second or third time, it'll go dead

If power saving did not kick in it will work when resumed.

Comment: been there - tried that - no effect... still loses pci wifi upon restore from suspend

Comment: Really, none of the network-manager commands do anything (modprobe will even remove the blank wifi in the dropdown menu).                  
Don't think it has anything to do with Network Manager. I even tried to switch to WICD but that actually messed it all up even worse and had to return to network-manager :-(